# Post a PHP value into an iframe using a JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I’m needing to post a PHP value into an iframe using a JavaScript.
The code I’m trying to use is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function autoSubmit1() {
             window.frames['Main'].location = 
                 "dropoutput1.php"$.post = "Technology:  rr.Technology.value";
         } 
    </script>
```

Previously, I was using the code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function autoSubmit1() {
              $.post('dropoutput1.php', 
                     {name1: rr.Technology.value},
                     function (output) {
                         $('#info').html(output).show();
                     }
              );
          }     
     </script>
```

to output to a div.
I believe I just do not know the syntax, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function autoSubmit1() {
         window.frames['Main'].location = 
             "dropoutput1.php"$.post = "Technology:  rr.Technology.value";
     } 
</script>
```

And you should change it to something like this
 (**only if you want to keep using the `window.frames['Main'].location` strategy**
(if not, use @DanFromGermany answer))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function autoSubmit1() {
         window.frames['Main'].location = "dropoutput1.php?name1="+rr.Technology.value;
     } 
</script>
```

This will make the frame change to the `dropoutput1.php` page and it will send the variable `name1` via `GET` (not via `POST` as you had before)

So, in your `dropoutput1.php` file remember to change `POST['name1']` to `GET['name1']`

Comment: in "dropoutput1.php?name1"+rr.Technology.value; I added = so it looks like this,

Comment: window.frames['Main'].location = "dropoutput02.php?name2="+rr.Technology.value;

Answer (score 0):

fill a hidden form, post it with javascript (`onload.test.submit` or something like that)

```
<form action="dropoutput1.php" method="post" name="test" target="nameOfYourIframeWindow">
<input type="hidden" name="Technology">
</form>
```

set `target=""` to your iframes `name=""` attribute

see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp